# In ArcGIS 9.3, how do I split a 3-band raster (.tiff) file and summarize the band values?

Tags: raster, arcgis-9.3

Using ArcGIS 9.3, I would like to make a new, single-band raster file that includes only one value: a summary of the three existing bands. The composite band is currently a composite .tiff file. Something like Band1 + band2 + band3 = newValue , for each pixel in the raster.  The new raster would contain only one output band, with the values for that band = newValue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this through Spatial Analyst.

Adding separate bands is very simple. When you are adding layer, go to your tiff and instead of adding, double-click on it. You will enter into its bands and now you can add these bands separately.

So, from this

[image: tiff]

you will enter into this

[image: bands]

Then you can use Raster calculator to do the sum. Open it from the Spatial Analyst toolbar.

[image: calculator]

And just write your equation for the 3 bands.

[image: calculation]

Then you will get a temporary raster which you can save on your computer.

[image: saving]

Hope this is what you need.