# Grass 7 / ArcGIS 9.3 - tiff to raster

Tags: raster, grass-gis, geotiff-tiff

Again a Grass 7 question. I have the output of a modelling run as matlab file, which I can export as tiff and load as geotiff. OK - now can I extract the data/convert this tiff into a raster proper? 
I also have ArcGIS 9.3, should this be the better way (I think this would work with the raster calculator - [In ArcGIS 9.3, how do I split a 3-band raster (.tiff) file and summarize the band values?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39342/in-arcgis-9-3-how-do-i-split-a-3-band-raster-tiff-file-and-summarize-the-ban), but I do not have ArcGIS at the moment to try this). Still curious if Grass 7 would be able to do this.

Additional info: 
The data contain calculated wind speeds, but the display is as color band 0-255. So the question is how to retrieve the winds speeds? I can only see them in Matlab, but in order to correlate and spacially reference I have to export the result - as tiff...

Thanks in advance, 
Peter

Answer (score 2):

You should not export the wind map as RGB GeoTIFF but rather as Floating point GeoTIFF.

Answer (score 1):

what is a raster proper ?

When you import a multiband raster in GRASS GIS, it is automatically splitted in these 3 color bands

The command:

`r.in.gdal -o input="test.tif" output="test"`

gives you 3 raster test.red, test.green and test.blue and each can be summarised.

If you want to combine these red, green and blue raster maps into a single map:

```
r.composite red="test.red" green="test.green" blue="test.blue" output="test"
```

Comment: Gene, thank you! 
My question was too imprecise. The data contain calculated wind speeds, but the display is as color band 0-255. So the question is how to retrieve the winds speeds? I can only see them in Matlab, but in order to correlate and spacially reference I have to export the result - as tiff...

Comment: You can see them because matlab transforms the byte data(which it has a range of 0-255) to actual data for each cell. figure out how transformation works, and apply the same routine.