# How to convert a 3-band image to a color-mapped one-band 8-bit image with ArcGIS or FME?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, fme-form

I have a 3 band image which needs to be converted to a 1 band image with colour-map so that I can assign different colours to the values. How can I first create a 1 band image out of RGB images with ArcGIS. I can´t find any settings to achieve this?

Comment: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39342/in-arcgis-9-3-how-do-i-split-a-3-band-raster-tiff-file-and-summarize-the-ban it needs a merge at the end